# galaxy s7 edge drag and drop

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

I have a user who has uprgraded from Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge to Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge.

My app has the ability to drag and drop playing card images.

The user indicates that this feature is not working on the S7 Edge but it did on the S6 Edge.

The dragging works, which suggests that the onTouch() and onDrag() are working but when an object is dropped it returns to its original position instead of the required position.

```
protected void measureDisplay() {
    // get info about screen size to determine style of images to use
    display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    // get the density of the display
    display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;
}

private void measureBoard(View v) {
    // get the current view width and height
    float viewWidth = v.getWidth();
    float viewHeight = v.getHeight();

    // extract the image offsets inside the view
    Matrix matrix = ((ImageView) v).getImageMatrix();
    float[] values = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(values);
    boardLeft = values[2]; // the X offset
    boardRight = viewWidth - boardLeft;
    boardTop = values[5]; // the Y offset
    boardBottom = viewHeight - boardTop;
    cardOffsetW = (boardRight - boardLeft) / 10;
    cardOffsetH = (boardBottom - boardTop) / 10;
}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with card drag-and-drop in my game; won't work on the S7. The dragging part works, but the onDragListener seems to be broken. In my app, the discard pile lights up when you start dragging, but that isn't happening, indicating the onDragListener never gets created. Did you ever find out what is going on ? I would love to know!

Comment: I just noticed that the user who sent me a screenshot had a new Samsung overlay feature enabled: Game Tools. I asked them to turn it off and try again with the drag-and-drop; I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: @Opus1217 I am still working on this issue.  My latest thinking is that the Edge screens have a different pixel size in practice compared to what is found out by querying the display.  I think the Edge panels may be excluded, since they hold different data.  If this is the case, the drop target may be off.  If the device was not so expensive, I would buy one and put it on the ADB and play with the code.  Do you have this ability?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an Edge, although I'm trying to find a friend who does :) I have reports not just on the S7 but also on other Samsungs (Note 2) running Android 6.0.1, but almost all are S7s. One possibility was that there is some type of transparent overlay or multi-window behavior that intercepts the drag-and-drop. My friendly user turned off Game Tools but it didn't help.

Comment: btw, I'm just happy to find another developer experiencing this problem. I was beginning to think I was just stupid ;)

Comment: Here's an interesting comment from a review that indicates it's not just a drop problem: "This app doesn't work well with the new Samsung s7 and I'm pretty sad because it worked amazing on my LG.  It's like it isn't recognizing my movements at all. I can't drag my discard or even meld anything"

Comment: I have replaced the code in the question with that associated with sizing the display and views.  Please comment on any errors.

Comment: Interesting that I think this bug report may be relevant: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214454 and suggests you are on the right track with the DPI question.

Comment: my friendliest user confirmed to me today that although they don't have a scaling feature listed under Settings>Display, they CAN drop the discard when they move it up and to the left of the discard pile. That would indicate the screen is indeed being condensed without the Android OS knowing about it. I am hoping they are running 6.0 and that the upgrade to 6.0.1 will expose the scaling in the DIsplay menu. Trying to find out more....

Comment: This is very good research. Take a look at my code above now.  I think it walks right into the trap you describe in your link to the bug report.

Comment: In my case I use a relative layout where I position the DrawPile and the DiscardPile to the left and right of a centered button. And for the scaling problem to manifest, it must be that the scaled display somehow is moving the on-screen images down and to the right from their "actual" positions. Is there a programmatic way to turn off Display Scaling?

Comment: I believe the scaling might be the issue.  This is related: http://www.androidauthority.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-updated-display-scaling-686324/

Comment: getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(Point outSize);

"Gets the real size of the display without subtracting any window decor or applying any compatibility scale factors. 
The size is adjusted based on the current rotation of the display. 

The real size may be smaller than the physical size of the screen when the window manager is emulating a smaller display..."

Comment: Although several friendly users told me my revised dragging worked (up and to the left) , none of them seemed to have access to Display Scaling through the standard menu, so I can't ask them to turn off Condensed mode to confirm that fixes the problem.

Comment: This is how to locate it using Nova Launcher: http://www.androidauthority.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-dpi-scaling-setting-680736/

Comment: @Opus1217 One user just sent me "I don't know what you did, but since I logged in with my Gmail account the problem with drag/drop and card re-ordering is working. I know that it wasn't just a couple of days ago."  Is it possible that he received an OTA update from Samsung.

Comment: Sounds quite possible - can you ask them to check whether they have the Display Scaling option and what it is set to?

Comment: @Opus1217 They have the option: "It shrinks things down on certain screens. For instance,  on my home screen when I open a folder I see more icons.  I have turned it on and I actually quite like it.  I tested yoir game with it in and it doesn't impact play.  It seems as though you are correct in saying the Samsung has released an OTA update."

Comment: @Opus1217 Can you craft some sort of an answer around the scaling option with links etc. that you have identified during the above exchange?  That way I can mark it as answered and give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

At least some of the problems with behind-the-scenes display scaling can be solved by finding out if the user has Samsung's Game Tuner installed. It changes the Resolution Ratio for any "Game" app, and possibly does it without ever being opened.

To resolve, ask users to specify Resolution Ratio for your game in Game Tuner (they can do that on a per-app basis). See more here: [DragEventListener not working on Samsung S7 (6.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044129/drageventlistener-not-working-on-samsung-s7-6-0)

I am working on an update for my game which would pop a message if they have Game Tuner installed.

Answer (score 0):

This app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evozi.displayscaling
will resolve the issue on Samsung devices.
In our game we faced with similar problem and solution was this settings change.
I hope that Samsung will provide fix with some next OS update so we do need to inform users about this bug and forcing them to change settings.